# Firefox 46.0 screen is black

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Yesterday (4/27/16) Ubuntu installed several updates.  Afterwards, when I started Firefox (46.0) the screen flashed white then went black.  It was not maximized.  I reduced the Ff page to about half my screen, then restarted.  It came up on the home page.  If I either maximize or increase the page size, the screen goes black. I have to reduce the page size and restart to get it back.

I'm not using any extensions.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed the black screen issue.  With a reduced page size (so that the screen wouldn't black out) I went to the Mozilla website.  The site automatically determined that I was using the latest version but offered the option (with a big green button) to "Refresh" the browser.  When I refreshed, the browser worked properly, and continues to work properly.

I still don't know what happened, nor why the refresh fixed the issue. It may be related to the bug mentioned by @Ignacio.

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark the questions as solved.

Comment: @vivi Will do, but I can't do that until the day after I post my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1576382